# How to select row in ImageJ ResultsTable?

Tags: imagej

From an ImageJ plugin, I would like to highlight a row in a ResultsTable, like when the row is clicked with the mouse. I suppose that the function [ResultsTable.selectRow(Roi roi)](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/measure/ResultsTable.html#selectRow-ij.gui.Roi-) can do this, but I do not know how to specify the row number using a Roi. How to create a Roi for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet to select a row by index:

```java
import java.awt.Frame;
import ij.WindowManager;
import ij.text.TextWindow;
...
int index = ...; // row index to highlight
Frame frame = WindowManager.getFrame("Results");
((TextWindow)frame).getTextPanel().setSelection(index, index);
```

I adapted it from the [ResultsTable source code](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/v1.52k/src/main/java/ij/measure/ResultsTable.java#L1406-L1431).